# Linux script running via crontab every 30 minutes to: [scans last 30 minutes of file] + [greps for values / error messages] + [emails result]

Tags: linux, sed, cron

I am looking to do the following via a crontab entry to run every 30 minutes:

1. Scan last 30 minutes of the log file, using sys time,
2. grep for ERROR keyword,
3. email the string containing the line with the ERROR keyword, along with 3 lines above the keyword and 3 lines below the keyword.

I've used the following command to scan for ERROR keyword:

```
sed -n '/2018-03-08 11:58/,/2018-03-08 12:03/p' debug.log | grep -A 3 -B 3 "ERROR"
```

All help appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: One of the issues you are having is in your `sed` line. What happens if there is no log-entry which contains `2018-03-08 11:58` or `2018-03-08 12:03`. A proper way to do this would be using `awk`, however we would need to see a sample of how the log-file looks like. Only then we could help you out. We could write something extremely general but it would be ugly and messy. A well tuned script might work better. So if you provide us some more info on the log-file.

Comment: you can specify `/2018-03-08 11:58/-3,/2018-03-08 12:03/+3p`, so you get the context lines you demand.

Answer (score 0):

I think points 1 and 2 have been addressed.

For the last one, you only need to redirect the output of your grep command to the error output; thus **cron** system will send it by e-mail.

For instance:

```
sed -n '/2018-03-08 11:58/,/2018-03-08 12:03/p' debug.log | grep -A 3 -B 3 "ERROR" >&2
```

Requirements:

- MAILTO variable must be defined (e.g. at the beginning of your cron definition file)
- an operational SMTP server must be installed on your operating system